# @ converted to %40 in GET

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, asciiencoding

I'm using http://jquery.malsup.com/form/  and I'm posting an e-mail address to a url using GET.

It looks like the @ in the email address is being converted to %40.

Will this be an issue for the site capturing the data?

Comment: Click and look at the url: http://www.google.com/#bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=8fc685d9ca728249&hl=en&q=%40

Comment: Did you actually try answering the question yourself? Also no, I don't think so, as long as you use [urldecode()](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.urldecode.php).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`%40` is the URL-encoded version of `@`. This conversion only takes place in the URL. The server will still see it as `@`, and if necessary you can even use JavaScript to decode it:

```
decodeURIComponent('%40'); // '@'
// or, to encode it back:
encodeURIComponent('@'); // '%40'
```

Here’s an example of a URL that will get parsed as you’d expect on the server-side:

```
http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/get?x=%40
```

If you [visit the page](http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/get?x=%40), you’ll see that it prints `@`, not `%40`.

Here’s an example of a URL that will get parsed as you’d expect on the client-side, by using `decodeURIComponent`:

```
http://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%40
```

If you [visit the page](http://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%40), you’ll see that the textarea’s contents are set to `@`, not `%40`.